# Android app not installing when installed as normal apk

Tags: android-studio, android-install-apk

When i run my project to my phone it's running successfully. But when i try to send the apk file using share it, the installation fails. I already tried disabling instant run in settings and clean my project but still it doesn't work.

I also try creating a new project and run it on my phone but when i send the apk file it also fail to install.

My classmates are also developing and android application in android studio and their apps can be shared by sending the apk file.

My conclusion is that i have a different settings in my Android studio.

Comment: Does the Android studio prints some log on the logcat or show a message?

Comment: connect your phone after sending apk and check your log

Comment: Can you help me how can i filter the log messages in logcat so i can get the necessary logs on installaltion?